# Navigate through Top Command's Pages in HP-UX

Tags: unix, process, hp-ux

I PuTTY to a HP-UX box, and when I run `top` command, it only displays the first 21 processes. I also see on the top right hand corner of the list there is a header that says `Page# 1/12`. I need to know, in such environment, how I can navigate/scroll through pages to view other processes. (I have tried everything from <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd>, and pretty much every key with <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> at no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate, use the following:

<kbd>j</kbd> : Next screen

<kbd>k</kbd> : Previous screen

<kbd>l</kbd> : First screen

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the scrollback (default is 200) and using SHIFT+PAGEUP/SHIFT+PAGEDOWN.

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-scrollback
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback

Depending on the environment/tools sometimes just spacebar works for me as well.

Comment: I always set the scrollback to 3000+. PuTTY'ing to HP UX with Ksh running, as I stated in my answer below, hitting k and j allow you to navigate between pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can scroll on top output, not sure about HP-UX though I believe it should be same behaviour, Did you try using number (eg. press 2 for second page, or n for next page ..just a guess )

There are couple of option if you want to see all process...

```
1. use htop where you can use page up/page down (or up and down arrow key) to scroll
2. run the top command only one iteration using -n option and take output in any file  

 top -b -n 1

3. ps -ef command can give you list of all process, ps command also have option to sort output based on %CPU or %MEM
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `htop` is not available on this box, and the admin is not going to install any tool other than the already installed application (security reasons). This version of `top` installed on HP-UX machine does not have `-b` flag. What I can do is to log it to the file and set the number of processes to some large number, i.e. `top -f top_output.txt -n100`, but this would defeat the whole purpose of my OP. And I do not know how relevant option (3) is (and using `ps` on HP-UX to get real physical memory [RSS] is tricky).